# Does the Great Revival and the Great Awakening refer to the same thing?

Tags: united-states

Does the Great  Revival and the Great Awakening refer to the same thing.  I am really confused.  I have encountered a sentence which says the Great Awakening (Revival) in the West promoted the abolitionist movement.  Does the Great Awakening (Revival) refer to the First or Second Great Awakening?
Here is the original sentence "The anti-slavery movement was closely tied to the Great Awakening (Revival) in the West, bringing the force of religion even more strongly in support of abolition. "
The entire chapter where this sentence is taken from is one the emancipation of African Americans.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where did you encounter the sentence? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the [site tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: Please - cite the sentence. History without sources is like dinner without food. It may have all the dishes and silverware, but it doesn't nourish.  I cannot make any sense unless I know who said what when in what context.  Given the context, it is likely that it is a reference to the [Third Great Awakening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_Great_Awakening)

Answer (score 1):

No. But they refer to the same type of (American) phenomenon called an "awakening."

In their 1991 book, "Generations," (the late) William Strauss and Neil Howe (S&H) offered an explanation for these types of events. They postulate that there are four different types of generations, about 20 years apart, in roughly an 80 year cycle. The purveyors of "Awakening" experiences are so-called Idealist generations born immediately after a major Anglo-American war. These wars are the Glorious Revolution/War of Spanish Succession, the American Revolution, the Civil War, and World War II.

According to this theory, the bunch of American children born in the "peace and prosperity" following the War of Spanish Succession became the Great Awakeners. They grew up in an economically prosperous and intellectually sterile era. Upon reaching adulthood in the 1730s and 1740s, they tried to compensate for the sterility of their youth by bringing about a religious awakening. Other generations had religious experiences of course, but the fervency and self-absorption of such experiences is unique to the Idealist generations. Late in life, Awakeners like Benjamin Franklin turned their attention to issues like "No taxation without representation," and "unite or die."

The Great Revival is sometimes known as the Second Great Awakening, and was a religious awakening much like the first one. It occurred during the 1820s and 1830samong the "Transcendental" generation (of Abraham Lincoln and Nathaniel Hawthorne) born after the American Revolution. [Transcendentalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendentalism) was the American version of European romanticism, representing a new wave of idealism that was a countercurrent to the rational empiricism of the "Republican" generation that won the American Revolution and launched America on the road to world power. (This Republican*generation was the 18th century version of the World War II generation.) Depending on their location, the "Transcendentalists" were either strongly for or against slavery, not "wishy-washy" like their parents.

The latest Idealist generation is the Baby Boom generation born after World War II inherited a prosperous world of peace and love and brotherhood from the World War II generation. In their young adulthood, the Boomers wondered "is this all there is?" and their answer to this question was ["Woodstock"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodstock), a 1969 multi-day rock concert that literally rocked the world, and world culture for decades to come. Unlike previous awakenings, the Boomers created a secular, not religious, awakening.

*The Republican generation is the name that S&H gave to the soldiers that won the American revolution. My preferred monicker is the "Continental" (Soldier) generation.